# Single or multiple solution of linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the two linear equations:
\begin{align}
x + xy^2 &= 40y\\ 
x - xy^2 &= -32y
\end{align}

I find that one solution for $(x,y)$ is $(12, 3)$. How can I determine if there are any other solutions?

Comment: Those aren’t linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

Adding both equations we get: $$x=4y$$ plugging this in the first equation we obtain: $$y^3-9y=0$$ and this can be written as
$$y(y^2-9)=0$$
so $$y=0$$ or $$y=\pm3$$
Can you finish?

Comment: ... a typo in your computation

Comment: Thank you for pointed out!